# gnu makefile what does goal1: goal2 ; @echo > /dev/null mean?

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu

Given the following makefile:

```
.PHONY: goal1
goal1: goal2 ; @echo > /dev/null mean

.PHONY: goal2
goal2:
    ... do some stuff...
```

I am not really sure how / why `goal1: goal2 ; @echo > /dev/null mean`
 works. It does exactly what I want it to do (it appears) but I am not sure if its safe because I don't understand it. I can't find documentation for that particualr syntax.

So what I think it means is:

- goal1 has a dependency of goal2
- the semicolon is a new line?
- the @echo > /dev/null is the recipie for goal1 (but what about the tab indent?)

What I want it to do when I do `make goal1` is:

- do actions for goal2
- Suppress any "nothing to do for goal1" type messages

And it does these things.

But can someone explain/confirm the syntax that I don't understand? - I found that example on some other question and it seemed to fit what I want, but there was no explanation.

Comment: Please [read the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html). Especially the [section about rule syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Syntax).

Comment: Slightly more accurate link to the [Rule Syntax section](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Syntax) of the documentation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ... ok, now I am feeling suitably embaressed...  I really was searching for this thinking it was a special syntax that I did not even think to look at the most basic part of the documentation :o

Comment: @RenaudPacalet thanks also for the specific link